# Code optimisation on EmailMessage

Tags: trigger, email-template, case, singleemailmessage, email2case

I have created a class and a trigger to be able to stop clients from sending email message on Closed Cases.

The code works as intended.
We tend to communicate with Clients using the quick action Email under the Case Feed tab.
But sometimes, clients try to communicate to us about new issues using an old email reply of a closed case.

Now, with the code I wrote, they receive an email informing them that the case is closed & that we are not communicating on the case anymore.

The code works as intended...
But since I am still learning on the platform, I have the feeling that my code is cumbersome.

How can I optimise and make my code more efficient?
Thanks

**Apex class:**

```
public class EmailManager {
@future
public static void sendEmailToCaseDeactivated(Set<Id> caseIds){

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<Case> lstCase = [SELECT Id, Status,ContactEmail FROM Case WHERE 
                          Status = 'Closed' AND
                          ContactEmail != Null AND
                          Id IN: caseIds];
    EmailTemplate templateId = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName =:'Smart_Community_Email_to_Case_Deactivated'];
   
    for(Case cas :  lstCase) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
        mail.setTemplateId(templateId.Id);
        String[] sendingTo = new String[]{cas.ContactEmail}; 
        mail.setToAddresses(sendingTo); 
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        allmsg.add(mail);
    }               
    Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg, false);
}

}
```

**Apex trigger:**

```
trigger IncomingEmailClosedCase on EmailMessage (before insert,after insert) {

if(trigger.isBefore) { 
    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(EmailMessage em: Trigger.New) {
        if (em.Incoming)
             caseIds.add(em.parentId);   
    }
    if(!caseIds.isEmpty())
        EmailManager.sendEmailToCaseDeactivated(caseIds);
}
if(trigger.isAfter){
    Map<Id,Id> mapOfCaseVsEM = new Map<Id,Id>();
    for(EmailMessage em: Trigger.New) {
        if (em.Incoming)
            mapOfCaseVsEM.put(em.parentId,em.Id);   
    }
    set<Id> todeleteEM = new Set<Id>();
    if(mapOfCaseVsEM.isEmpty()) return;
    for(Case lstCase : [SELECT Id, Status,ContactEmail FROM Case WHERE 
                      Status = 'Closed' AND
                      ContactEmail != Null AND
                      Id IN: mapOfCaseVsEM.keyset()]){
        if(mapOfCaseVsEM.containsKey(lstCase.Id)){
            Id emId = mapOfCaseVsEM.get(lstCase.Id);
            todeleteEM.add(emId);
        } 
    } 
    if(!todeleteEM.isEmpty())   delete [ select Id from EmailMessage where id in :todeleteEM];
}
}
```

Comment: Other than putting your trigger in a framework, any changes I can see you might want to make seem to me to be trivial. Getting your unit test created to cover both positive and negative conditions, plus provide maximum code coverage is where you should be expending your efforts at this point in time.

Comment: Despite my long answer, I agree with @crmprogdev. Aside from unit testing, your main code avoids the major neophyte pitfalls, such as queries inside loops and nested for loops instead of maps. In fact, I've seen worse code from some people who can put Junior Developer on their CV/resume, so you're on the right track. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Don't Skimp on Curly Brackets

You may think that you're saving some space/typing with:

```
if (em.Incoming)
    caseIds.add(em.parentId);
```

But you're actually risking a very subtle bug. Commenting a line or adding a new line might not be codified in the if statement correctly, leading to unexpected logic errors or compilation errors. It's not worth it.

## Don't Make Caller Check For Empty

```
if(!caseIds.isEmpty())
    EmailManager.sendEmailToCaseDeactivated(caseIds);
```

Generally speaking, the caller should not worry about sending an empty list. The method being called should do the appropriate check. This consolidates the logic to a single location, a principle called DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself):

```
public static void sendEmailToCaseDeactivated(Set<Id> caseIds){
    if(caseIds.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
```

## Don't Query Unnecessary Fields

```
for(Case lstCase : [SELECT Id, Status,ContactEmail FROM Case WHERE
```

You query three fields, but you only use Id. A query does *not* need to include a field in the fields list unless you intend to use that field later. You can filter on fields that are not queried. Note that if you select at least one field besides Id, you don't need to query Id, as you **always** get this field for free, even if you don't ask for it.

## Save Nulls For The End

The great part about maps is you can often avoid the if statements. The following logic is identical:

```
                    Id IN: mapOfCaseVsEM.keyset()]){
        todeleteEM.add(mapOfCaseVsEM.get(lstCase.Id));
    } 
    todeleteEM.remove(null);
```

This saves quite a bit of execution, as calling containsKey + get is twice as expensive in CPU time as just calling get. Use this when possible. Note that the final revision uses a more advanced technique that removes the need to remove null, too.

## Avoid Unnecessary Queries

```
if(!todeleteEM.isEmpty())   delete [ select Id from EmailMessage where id in :todeleteEM];
```

You can save a query here by simply constructing the objects in memory:

```
EmailMessage[] messages = new EmailMessage[0];
for(Id toDeleteId: todeleteEM) {
    messages.add(new EmailMessage(Id=toDeleteId));
}
delete messages;
```

Or, even better, you can clone the Map, trim the excess values, and delete what's left:

```
Map<Id, EmailMessage> messagesToDelete = Trigger.newMap.clone();
messagesToDelete.retainAll(toDeleteEm);
delete messagesToDelete.values();
```

## Don't Check Empty Lists If You Don't Need To

Note, it's not necessary to check if a list is empty before calling a DML operation on it. The system internally does this, so adding your own if statement uses CPU time unnecessarily. In tests I've performed, this can add as much as 1/3rd of a second to total execution time if you use this technique frequently.

However, things like Messaging.sendEmail don't do this check, so you'll still need to use an if statement in those cases, for now.

```
if(!allmsg.isEmpty()) {
    Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg, false);
}
```

## Consolidate Logic

You can extract the Incoming check to a single location to reduce your code. You'll see this in the final revision.

## Don't Bind If You Don't Need To

```
EmailTemplate templateId = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName =:'Smart_Community_Email_to_Case_Deactivated'];
```

The `:` is a binding statement. This executes some Apex. You should prefer to avoid using this syntax for literal values, as it introduces unnecessary overhead.

```
EmailTemplate templateId = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'Smart_Community_Email_to_Case_Deactivated'];
```

## You Don't Need Those Variables

You use a few temporary variables when you don't need to. If a parameter is only used once, just use it directly. The exception to this is when the lgoic would get cumbersome to follow (e.g. looking up 3 or more map values in a nested map or related maps).

## Inconsistent Variable Names

You've chosen some poor variables, like calling the email template emailTemplateId. It's not an ID, it's an EmailTemplate. Also, lstCase and the like are Hungarian Notation, but you don't use those consistently. Use them all the time, or not at all. I prefer avoiding Hungarian Notation, instead preferring to name my variables based on what they *are*. The data type should be inferred from the name.

### Good Names

`caseIds` tells me it's a List or Set of Case Ids. Some would argue it should be `setCaseIds` or `lstCaseIds`, but it's usually obvious from context, and I don't recommend Hungarian Notation as a general rule.

### Bad Names

`mapOfCaseVsEM` is a bad name. It's Hungarian Notation, but still fails to convey what this is actually meant to be. It's obvious from the code, but it could have been called `caseIdToMessageId` or something like like. `Vs` implies opposition, but it's not, it's a mapping of X **to** Y.

`for(Case lstCase` is especially egregious here. `lstCase` is a ... Case. Not a List of Cases, just a single record. In longer code, this could be confusing. I prefer the nomenclature of `sObjectNameRecord`, such as `caseRecord` or `accountRecord`. Be descriptive, and accurate.

## `List<Object>` vs `Object[]`

As a matter of preference, I do hate typing any more than necessary, so I typically use the `Object[]` data type when possible to avoid extra typing. I also find it easier to read, but this may have to with my history of Java and C++ programming.

## Switch Statements

A relatively new feature, switch statements, makes the code more legible. I'd suggest you use it when possible. One specific use case is when you use the TriggerOperation enum to clearly outline what trigger context you're in.

---

## Final Revision

```
trigger IncomingEmailClosedCase on EmailMessage (before insert,after insert) {
    Map<Id, Id> caseIdsToEmailMessageIds = new Map<Id, Id>();
    for(EmailMessage messageRecord: Trigger.new) {
        if(messageRecord.Incoming) {
            caseIdsToEmailMessageIds.put(messageRecord.ParentId, messageRecord.Id);
        }
    }
    if(caseIdsToEmailMessageIds.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    switch on Trigger.operationType {
        when BEFORE_INSERT {
            EmailManager.sendEmailToCaseDeactivated(caseIdsToEmailMessageIds.keySet());
        }
        when AFTER_INSERT {
            Set<Id> messageIdsToDelete = new Set<Id>();
            for(Case caseRecord: [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Status = 'Closed' AND ContactEmail != Null AND Id IN: mapOfCaseVsEM.keyset()]){
                messageIdsToDelete.add(caseIdsToEmailMessageIds.get(caseRecord.Id));
            } 
            Map<Id, EmailMessage> messagesToDelete = Trigger.newMap.clone();
            messagesToDelete.retainAll(messageIdsToDelete);
            delete messagesToDelete.values();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class EmailManager {
    @future public static void sendEmailToCaseDeactivated(Set<Id> caseIds){
        if(caseIds.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        Case[] caseRecords = [
            SELECT ContactEmail 
            FROM Case
            WHERE Status = 'Closed' AND ContactEmail != Null AND Id IN :caseIds];
        EmailTemplate templateId = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'Smart_Community_Email_to_Case_Deactivated']?.Id;
        if(templateId != null) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
            for(Case caseRecord: caseRecords) {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                message.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
                message.setTemplateId(templateId);
                message.setToAddresses(new String[]{ cas.ContactEmail }); 
                message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                messages.add(message);
            }
            Messaging.sendEmail(messages, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I've left out some more advanced topics, like Trigger Frameworks, as they're not strictly necessary here, but you should read more about a trigger framework for future work.

Please study this code carefully, as I've token a lot of care fo try and build this code exactly as I would (assuming I'm not using a Trigger Framework, which in reality I would be).

Comment: Thank you so much for all the effort in your answer. That is a great lesson there. Thanks again